# Lift/Scala: How to redirect to a page and add a cookie?

Tags: lift

I need to redirect user to the homepage and add a cookie.
Following code only redirects but doesnt add a cookie.

```
S.addCookie(HTTPCookie("foo", "bar"))
S.redirectTo("/")
```

Please advise. Thanks.

```
object Auth extends RestHelper {
  def init() {
    LiftRules.dispatch.append(Auth)
  }


  serve {
    case "auth" :: "xxvvvxx" :: Nil Get request => {
      val firstName = request.param("first_name").openOrThrowException("First Name not available")          
      val session = request.param("session").openOrThrowException("Session not available")                    
      S.addCookie(HTTPCookie("session", session))
      S.redirectTo("/")
    }    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work:

```
case "auth" :: "xxvvvxx" :: Nil Get request => {
  val firstName = request.param("first_name").openOrThrowException("First Name not available")          
  val session = request.param("session").openOrThrowException("Session not available")                    
  new RedirectResponse("/", request, HTTPCookie("session", session).setPath("/").setMaxAge(999999))
}
```

[ref1](https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/master/web/webkit/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/http/LiftResponse.scala), [ref2](https://blog.knoldus.com/2012/09/09/play-with-cookies-using-scala-and-lift/)

Comment: This is correct, but arguably due to a bug in Lift---namely, that we don't take `S.responseCookies` into account when [handling `ResponseShortcutExceptions`](https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/master/web/webkit/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/http/LiftServlet.scala#L506). Would welcome a GitHub issue on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

`S` has also the following redirect method (documentation [here](https://liftweb.net/api/31/api/net/liftweb/http/S.html#redirectTo(where:String,func:()=%3EUnit):Nothing))

```
def redirectTo(where: String, func: () ⇒ Unit): Nothing
```

That takes a function to be executed after the redirect.

So you can also do something like this

```
S.redirectTo("/", () => S.addCookie(HTTPCookie("session", session).setPath("/").setMaxAge(999999)))
```